# C++ output formatting using setw and setfill

Tags: c++, output-formatting

In this code, I want to have numbers printed in special format starting from 0 to 1000 preceding a fixed text, like this:

> Test 001
>   Test 002
>   Test 003
>   ...
>   Test 999

But, I don't like to display it as

> Test 1
>   Test 2
>   ...
>   Test 10
>   ...
>   Test 999

What is wrong with the following C++ program making it fail to do the aforementioned job?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using  namespace std;

const string TEXT = "Test: ";

int main()
{

    const int MAX = 1000;
    ofstream oFile;

    oFile.open("output.txt");


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        oFile << std::setfill('0')<< std::setw(3) ;
        oFile << TEXT << i << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put `setw` and `setfill` just beofre `i`: `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) and [`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) is for the *next* output operation only. So in your case you set it for the output of `TEXT`.

Instead do e.g.

```
oFile << TEXT << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i << endl;
```

Comment: For those of you reading this now: [`setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) actually works for **ALL** following output operations on the stream. Try with e.g:
`std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(20) << "hi" << '\n' << std::setw(20) << "bar" << '\n';`